# What is the algorithm behind nested comments?

Tags: php, algorithm, database-design, comments

I want to learn the comment displaying algorithm behind Reddit. How is a comment related with its child and so on? How they are stored in the database?

Lets say

```
comment1
-comment2
--comment3
-comment4
--comment5
--comment6
---comment7
----comment8
comment9
```

How to display comment5 which is after comment4 which is after comment1? What is the idea behind this sequencing? And how to relate them in the database?

Comment: Each comment probably has a "parent" column which contains the comment id for the parent.

Comment: Since you mentioned Reddit, you might want to take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4278003/how-is-designed-programmed-the-reddit-comment-system/4278052#4278052

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AS @Rafe said, the actual storage is pretty easy, it would be something like:

```
|  id  |   name   | parent |
|  1   | comment1 |    0   |
|  2   | comment2 |    1   |
|  3   | comment3 |    2   |
|  4   | comment4 |    1   |
|  5   | comment5 |    4   |
|  6   | comment6 |    4   |
|  7   | comment7 |    6   |
|  8   | comment8 |    7   |
|  9   | comment9 |    0   |
```

Of course actually getting information from this is (arguably) the hard part.  You can of course get the children of a comment with something like: `SELECT * FROM table WHERE parent='4'` will give you all the children of comment4.  But counting children, listing all the children in hierarchical order would be a bit harder.  Other answers may provide more information on that.

Answer (score 6):

It is called **hierarchy**. Each comment either has no parent comment, or has one parent comment. This way you can display every "*top level*" comment (thanks to the fact they have no parent comments), then child comments for each of them etc. etc.

And the database structure may look like this for `comments` table:

- `id` field identifying single comment,
- `parent_id` being set to parent's ID or not set (set to `NULL` or set to `0`),
- `created` - timestamp for comment creation,
- `content` - actual comment content,
- any additional field you need,

Answer (score 3):

Pretty much what @Rafe Kettler noted - comments can have parent columns. However, if you want a more detailed and in-depth algorithm to use as a pattern for your implementation, take a look at [this message threading algorithm](http://www.jwz.org/doc/threading.html).